# Inserting data in Textarea into database with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm doing a form submission with AJAX. Input values in the form are inserted into the database without any problems. However, the text (data) I write in the textarea is not inserted into the database. I think this is due to the script I wrote. I did some research but couldn't find any resource on this issue. I wonder why the data in the textarea is not inserted into my database?

My script :

```
 <script>
    
    function NewTicket() {

        var ticket = $("#newticket").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            data : ticket,
            url  : "ajax.php",
            success : function (e) {
                if ($.trim(e) == "success") {
                    swal({
                        title: "Success",
                        text: "Gotcha",
                        icon: "success",
                        closeOnClickOutside: false,
                        buttons: false,
                        timer: 3000
                    });
                    $("#new_ticket").hide();
                    $("#success").show();
                } else if ($.trim(e) == "error") {
                    swal({
                        title: "Error",
                        text: "Something went wrong.",
                        icon: "error",
                        closeOnClickOutside: false,
                        buttons: false,
                        timer: 3000
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

</script>
<script src="/js/simplemde.min.js"></script>
<script>
    new SimpleMDE({
        element: document.getElementById("textarea"),
        spellChecker: false,
        hideIcons: ['side-by-side', 'fullscreen', 'preview', 'guide', 'image', 'link'],
    });
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<form action="" id="newticket" onsubmit="return false;" name="newticketlo" method="POST">
<h4>New Ticket</h4>

<div class="Name">
    <label class="form-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-primary" >
</div>
<div class="EmailAddress">
    <label class="form-label">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-primary" >
</div>

<div class="col-12 col-md-12 mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-primary" name="subject">
</div>

<div class="col-12 col-md-12 mb-4">
    <label class="form-label">Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control form-primary" id="textarea" name="message"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $getData['id']; ?>">

<div class="Settin">
    <button onclick="NewTicket();" class="btn btn-two btn-rounded font-weight-semibold text-3 btn-px-5 btn-py-2 d-none d-md-block me-3 me-lg-0 mb-4">Submit</button>
</div>
```

PHP :

```
if ($_POST) {

    $customer_id = (trim(strip_tags($_POST['id'])));
    $subject = (strip_tags($_POST['subject']));
    $message = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

    $query=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO support SET
    customer_id=:customer_id,
    subject=:subject,
    message=:message
    ");
    $update=$query->execute(array(
    'customer_id' => $customer_id,
    'subject'     => $subject,
    'message'     => $message,
    ));

    if ($update) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
}else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: You showed us neither the textarea HTML within your form, or the PHP code which does the insert to the database. In other words, all the interesting bits where something might go wrong with a specific field are missing from your question. Also what debugging have you done to try and narrow down the issue? We cannot run your code, and not all mistakes are always visible from reading code. You could at least do some basic tests to see if the textarea data is reaching the PHP script or not (for example). Please provide a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, totally my fault. Now I have added other codes as well.

Comment: And the debugging? I've just done a simple test and it looks like the data will reach the server ok (https://jsfiddle.net/0bjeocL5/) but I can't run your PHP code. If you `var_dump($_POST);` can you see the message data in there? And after you run `$message = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));` what is the value of `$message` at that point? And what do you actually get in the database in the end for that field - is it NULL, or just empty, or what?

Comment: P.S. `htmlentities` is an _output_ filter, it's not to be used when saving input data. It's only there to guard against the possibility of XSS attacks (and/or to ensure HTML markup isn't parsed by the browser). A database can't suffer from that so you should not use it when inserting into the database. Effectively you're corrupting whatever was input - if you were to output that later in some other context (e.g. CSV file or something) it wouldn't matter if there's HTML in there, it can't do any harm. So only use that when you `echo` the data back into the page.

Comment: And `strip_tags` is equally useless in this context, for the same reason, and it's not as effective as htmlentities or htmlspecialchars anyway - so use one of those (you can google to find out the differences) whenever you echo any user-generated data.

Comment: My PHP file is "var_dump($_POST);" I added. And this code "$message = nl2br(strip_tags($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));" I changed it to "$message = $_POST['message']". When I checked, I got the following output:
array(3) {
   ["subject"]=>
   string(9) "TEST"
   ["message"]=>
   string(13) "TEST MESSAGE"
   ["id"]=>
   string(1) "1"
}

Comment: Ok so the value is being passed to the PHP correctly, so I don't see any reason it wouldn't reach the database. You didn't say what you're actually seeing in the database for that field.

Comment: Nothing. Nothing is coming into the database. When I remove the textarea and make input type text it works fine. I wonder if it could be due to the SimpleMDE I'm using?

Comment: What is SimpleMDE? Is that a rich text editor? But if you're seeing the expected data in $_POST["message"] then it's past the point where a front-end tool could be causing a problem.

Comment: `Nothing is coming into the database`...you mean no row is inserted at all? Or it's inserted a row but the "message" field is empty?

Comment: The ID and subject have been inserted into the database. But the message is not inserted.

Comment: So the field is still NULL? Or you see an empty space?

Comment: I see an empty space.

Comment: If `$message` really contains what you told me then I don't see how it's possible. Maybe the field in the database is too small to hold the inserted text, or something?

Comment: Ah, now I fixed the problem! The problem is that the "message" column in the database is TEXT. I did VARCHAR and it was fine. Now everything works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, now I fixed the problem! The problem is that the "message" column in the database is TEXT. I did VARCHAR and it was fine. Now everything works smoothly.

But one more problem occurred.

Message data is not sent when submitting the form for the first time. But on the second try, the message data is inserted into the database. Why is the message data not being inserted into the database on the first try? It's frustrating to try twice. What is causing this?

Comment: You can't ask a question inside an answer. Stackoverflow is not a forum :-). It's good your original problem was solved, you can keep that in your answer, but you need to make a new question about the new issue.